# How to create a column after inserting a table and import data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to create a column after inserting a table and import data
I want create a column in table with 20 millions records
notice : When I want to create from design in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio the process field

```
+-------+-------+-------+.........
| Col_B | Col_C | Col_A |  NEW   .
+-------+-------+-------+.........
| x     | y     | 3     |  NULL  .
| s     | u     | 4     |  NULL  .
| h     | z     | 33    |  NULL  .
| t     | t     | 14    |  NULL  . 
| m     | m     | 77    |  NULL  .
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD NEW VARCHAR(128) NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding it like this with a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD YourNewColumn VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Or if you want it NULL:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD YourNewColumn VARCHAR(100) NULL
```

You may be getting an error if you're trying to create a NOT NULL column without a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Alter` the Table to add a New Column or modify the Properties of an Existing Column.

To Add A new Column You can Try this

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(50)
```

The Column will be Added and the Values will be `NULL`